# Problems using the "crop" package and printing cam options using LyX

Tags: xetex, lyx, crop

I'm having a little difficulty having default variables (with a custom page size) to load properly on the pdf.

I am using the following preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[
  noinfo,
  cam,
  cross,                % crosses as marks
  width=7.25in,         % the width of the galley
  height=8.75in,        % the height of the galley
  center                % actual page is centered on the galley
]{crop}
```

When I am typing a plain document, the crop marks appear. Unfortunately, the document that I use that has the same preamble but with the problem of everything appearing is a heavily modified and inclusive document with graphics and other sundry bits.

I'm not sure if any of this makes sense, but basically, take away all the graphics and heavy modification, and the crop marks appear. Include heavy modification, and they disappear. Is this making sense?

Comment: Please always post a minimal example for this. You just wrote a little excerpt but it is not compilable. For more information, see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample.

Comment: I can't without including an enormous source. I can't replicate it without including some rather large files.

Comment: The best approach then is a "bisect" approach. Delete half of your document, try to reproduce, if you cannot, then go back and delete the other half. Keep proceding until you get a minimal document. Note that "minimal" does not necessarily mean "small".

Comment: I found my solution; it had nothing to do with graphics, but rather my understanding of the crop package. Posted below (hopefully someone will learn from my naiveté).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Solution

I kept digging around searching both XeLaTeX support files and found I completely misunderstood the *purpose* of the "crop" package.

The "crop" package is designed to place various sundry post-production marks on paper that is larger in size than the actual page of content. My misunderstanding was that in either the `geometry` package or in LyX's menues my page dimensions (the actual *printed* page, not the oversized `crop` package's dimensions) matched each other.

Thus, there was no crop marks because the page size itself was the size of the cropped area.

### To Tweak:

- In LyX: Make sure your page dimensions under Document > Settings... > Page Layout are actually *smaller* than whatever oversized page you might have for your bleed/crop marks. Then, in your LaTeX Preamble, make sure your settings for page size when using `crop` are *larger* than your finished and printed document size.
- When using LaTeX et al, make sure your `geometry` is set to be smaller in page dimensions than when you invoke `crop` in your preamble.

I hope this helps.
[image: Document > Settings... > Page Layout]
[image: LaTeX Preamble section in LyX]